# How do I remove a broken terminal command in OSX?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I installed `protobuf 2.5` using homebrew but wanted to upgrade to the latest version. I ran `brew uninstall protobuf@2.5` and then `brew install protobuf`.

However now when I run the `protoc` command I get the error:

`-bash: /usr/local/opt/protobuf@2.5/bin/protoc: No such file or directory`

I tried running `brew unlink protoc && brew link protoc` but the error still persists. How do I go about removing the association of protoc with the deleted directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you’ve installed a newer version of protobuf, but your symlinks are still pointing to the old version. Clean up again:

```
brew uninstall protobuf@2.5
brew unistall protobuf
brew unlink protobuf
```

At this point, `which protobuf` should return empty. If it returns a file or link, remove that manually, then brew install again.

Hope this helps.